# There is or there are?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, singular-vs-plural

I just came across this paragraph:

*There **is** so many incredible women that nobody can agree on which one are the best ones. Just for your pleasure and to make everyone happy we have agreed on a list of the 23 most beautiful women.*

Why did the write use "is" and not "are"? the word *women* is a plural word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mistake

Comment: @MaulikV I believe there could be a better answer than it is a mistake. I don't think it is a mistake. **Is** is used instead of **are**, not broadly though.

Comment: I did not find any evidence of this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297975/is-this-a-grammar-mistake-i-got-this-from-the-usa-today-website#comment669654_297975. Please post the link.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Right you are. [Have a look](https://www.google.com/#q=%22nobody+can+agree+on+which+one+are+the+best+ones%22&safe=off&start=10). I  could find nothing from _USA Today_ anywhere in that list. Moreover, I tried [this search](http://www.usatoday.com/search/%22incredible%20women%22/), too.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was a sponsored content from USA Today. http://www.risottop.com/en/cheesy/the-15-most-beautiful-women-in-the-world/?utm_medium=taboola-en&utm_source=taboola&utm_content=acv0026&utm_source=taboola-en&utm_medium=referral&utm_term=usatodaydemo&utm_campaign=TAB_EN-ROW_d_Safeold08c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mistake, and it is not the only mistake. It should read **which ones are the best ones.** There should also be commas surrounding the clause **and to make everyone happy**.